# Vimeo - How to check if a video exists and playable?

Tags: php, vimeo

My client has a video uploaded in vimeo.com that does not play.
When I access the url with https://vimeo.com/videoid, it gives the response "Video conversion failed".

How can I get this response ?

I have gone through the API in developer.vimeo.com and am not able to find one.

Tried the following ways to solved which did not help.
1. get_headers(vimeo.com/videoid);
2. http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/videoid

Comment: What information are you looking for in your response? The status of the conversion? The reason the conversion failed? Or just more information about the clip?

Comment: I want to know whether the video exists for that videoid.

Answer (score 3):

when you call the api https://api.vimeo.com/videos/videoId, If you get a 200  Ok response, that response will contain a flag call status.

you can check to see if status is available or transcoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HEAD request method using the video URL.

```php
function check_remote_video_exists($video_url) {

    $headers = @get_headers($video_url);

    return (strpos($headers[0], '200') > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Check your vimeo URL like so:

```php
if (check_remote_video_exists('YOUR_VIMEO_VIDEO_URL')) {

    // video exists, do stuff

} else {

    // video does not exist, do other stuff

}
```

Hope this helps someone.